# What is more acceptable "Easy admission" or "comfortable admission"?

Tags: word-choice

When the admission to a university it's not so difficult,  what is the more acceptable in using by English native speakers?

> "Our university has an **easy admission**"
>
> "Our university has a **comfortable admission**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our university has an easy admission process.
>   Our university has easy admission standards.

I can't get using "admission" as a noun in your example, seems like it needs something else. So I made it an adjective instead.

*comfortable* does not work in this context. That would be more like *relaxed* or *to be at ease*.

Comment: In *an easy admission process*, the last two words are both nouns. Note than in idiomatic American English, it would be called *an easy **admissions** process* with the first noun in the plural.